# Meteorjs: HTTP.get is retrieving data but isn't returning anything to the helper function variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb, http, meteor

I have the following code that reads a json file:

```
Meteor.methods({
    getPlaces: function(){
        return HTTP.get(Meteor.absoluteUrl("/places.json"), function(e, r) {
                console.log(r.data);
                return r.data;
            });
    }
})
```

The console shows that its retrieving the data just fine.
Here is the part of my helper function for the template I want to display 'Places' in:

```
testing: function(){
    return Meteor.call("getPlaces");
}
```

& here is my loop in the template where it is supposed to show:

```
{{#each testing}}
    <li>{{testing.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

But it seems like I'm not calling the function right as the loop doesn't show anything. I've tested the loop by giving it random data which it works fine with but whenever I call Meteor.call or even HTTP.get directly on 'testing' it doesn't give me anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two essential problems here:

1. You're using [`HTTP.get`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_get) asynchronously when you don't need to.
2. You're trying to use [`Meteor.call`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call) synchronously when you can't as it won't work like that.

#### Explanation of 1:

In supplying a callback to `HTTP.get`, you're telling Meteor to allow code execution to continue beyond that line, and pass the result of the call to the callback function.  As a result, the actual method function finishes execution and will return `undefined` (which will be passed back to the calling function as `null` via EJSON) well before your actual HTTP call has returned.  When that happens, the result will be logged, but even though you're `return`ing the results in the *callback*, the enclosing method function won't care as it will have completed execution long before.

There are several ways to deal with this, the simplest being: *don't pass a callback*.  On the server, you can use `HTTP.get` synchronously by not passing a callback, in which case code will cease executing until the results come back, and they will actually be returned to the client.  Note that you *cannot* do this if you use `HTTP.get` on the client.  Other ways of dealing with this involve [Futures](https://www.discovermeteor.com/patterns/5828399) or [Promises](http://blog.east5th.co/2015/08/03/returning-promises-synchronously/) (better), but are unnecessary here.

#### Explanation of 2:

This is more complicated to resolve, but is fundamental to Meteor and Javascript.  If you're calling an asynchronous function and you want to use the result, you need to supply a callback (or use promises).  You can't just expect it to work inline for the same reasons given above.  So some changes need to be made:

1. Don't call a method from within a template helper.  You've no idea how often the template helper will run (it depends on all sorts of reactive things), so this is an essentially unbounded amount of traffic on the websocket that you're committing to.  Call them when something happens (template is rendered, event handler, a specific piece of data changes (i.e. within an [`autorun`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) block)), but not in a helper function.
2. Store the result in a reactive data source, otherwise even if you successfully receive it and put it somewhere, your UI won't update with the results.

So:

```
Template.yourTemplate.onCreated(function () {
  this.places = new ReactiveVar()
  Meteor.call("getPlaces", (err, res) => {
    // do some error handling here
    this.places.set(res)
  })
})


{{#each Template.instance.places.get}}
  <li>{{name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

A few notes:

- You need to install the [*reactive-var*](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg) package, which inexplicably isn't provided out of the box, for this to work: `meteor add reactive-var`.
- You could return the data via a template helper which uses `Template.instance().places.get()`, but you can just do it in-line in the template, which seems easier to me.
- If the result of the first method call aren't sufficient and you need to update the results, do this in an event handler, or an autorun block as required.  If the server needs to be able to *push* data directly to the client rather than waiting for requests for an update, then methods are the wrong tool - you need to be using Meteor's [pub/sub](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publishandsubscribe) model.